# Tethering android devices together

Tags: applications, tethering

I am very low-tech, but I have a very smart phone!  an android 2.2.1  I have recently discovered a wonderful application called tether, or tethering where you connect your phone & lap top or pc w/ a usb cord and from there the phone acts like a modem & wa-la! you get the internet! I just purchased the newest Android Tablet (3.0), an ASUS... okay My question is really this:  Can I tether my android phone to my Android tablet and get the same or different results? And if so, how? like with what type of cord would I connect these 2 devices, as there are no usb ports on the tablet. There are, however HDMI ports.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Android Settings, the wireless then enable "portable wi-fi hotspot"

Then connect to that wifi using your tablets wifi manager. Then you should have internet

Answer (score 1):

Kurru basically has it right, except that the `portable wi-fi hotspot` application will most likely require another monthly fee from your provider.

As far as wired tethering between devices, this is not possible. The protocols do not exist for android devices to accept external network connections through cables.

A very easy solution (if you are comfortable rooting your device), is [Wifi Tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/downloads/list). I use this app constantly, and works exactly as Kurru described:

1. Install
2. Run application
3. Press "Tether" button
4. Select "Android Hotspot" from available wireless access points on your tablet

And bam! You're done! As a personal user, i have to say this is the single best advantage to rooting a phone, and 100% worth it.

Comment: Here in the UK we don't have such bad mobile providers, but if you do, I'd recommend install http://www.cyanogenmod.com/ or another root package to obtain it

Comment: running [Unrevoked](http://unrevoked.com/) will work if you have an HTC device, otherwise any root will do. Then follow the link provided earlier for the Wifi Tether application and you're home free!